# Erro ao fazer upload de um arquivo AngularJS+Vraptor

Tags: java, angularjs, upload, vraptor

Tenho um sistema onde consigo fazer upload de arquivos atraves de uma biblioteca do Angular (`ng-file-upload`), porém se a o arquivo é maior que 3MB quando tento fazer o upload tenho os seguintes erros:

> GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path
>   [/Union] threw exception br.com.caelum.vraptor.InterceptionException:
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.InterceptionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are validation errors and you
>   forgot to specify where to go. Please add in your method something
>   like:
>   validator.onErrorUse(page()).of(AnyController.class).anyMethod(); or
>   any view that you like. If you didn't add any validation error, it is
>   possible that a conversion error had happened.    at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.invokeMethod(StepInvoker.java:54)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are validation
>   errors and you forgot to specify where to go. Please add in your
>   method something like:
>   validator.onErrorUse(page()).of(AnyController.class).anyMethod(); or
>   any view that you like. If you didn't add any validation error, it is
>   possible that a conversion error had happened.    at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.validator.Messages.assertAbsenceOfErrors(Messages.java:108)
>     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.validator.Messages$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.assertAbsenceOfErrors(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultResult.use(DefaultResult.java:79)
>     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultResult$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.use(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.union.controller.CORSInterceptor.intercept(CORSInterceptor.java:25)

Nessa segunda exception da um erro no meu interceptor que trata o CORS:

```
@Intercepts
public class CORSInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private Result result;
    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @BeforeCall
    public void intercept() throws InterceptionException {
        // Fix your origin if possible for security reasons
        String origin = request.getHeader("origin") != null ? request.getHeader("origin") : "*";

        result.use(Results.status()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin); //Linha 25
        result.use(Results.status()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        result.use(Results.status()).header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Type, Location");
    }
}
```

Esse é meu método que recebe a imagem do front e a salva em um diretório:

```
@Post
@Path(value = "/imagem")
public void salvaImagem(UploadedFile file) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("SALVAR IMAGEM");
    try{
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(file.getFile());
        File fotoSalva = new File(DIRETORIO_UPLOAD, file.getFileName());
        System.out.println(fotoSalva);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fotoSalva);
        while (in.available() != 0) {
            fos.write(in.read());
        }
        fos.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Estou validando o upload no `front` pra ele aceitar arquivos até 10MB, e está tudo certo, o problema mesmo é que o `back-end` não consegue pegar esses arquivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Na verdade foi um pouco de falta de atenção da minha parte, na [documentação do Vraptor](http://www.vraptor.org/pt/docs/download-e-upload/) diz que o valor padrão de upload para cada arquivo é de `2MB` então tenho que sobrescrever as funções de Upload:

```
@Specializes
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomMultipartConfig extends DefaultMultipartConfig {

    // alteramos o tamanho total do upload para 50MB
    public long getSizeLimit() {
        return 50 * 1024 * 1024;
    }

    // alteramos o tamanho do upload de cada arquivo para 20MB
    public long getFileSizeLimit() {
        return 20 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
}
```

Ou então posso utilizar essa anotação, onde defino o tamanho pra 40mb total e 10mb por arquivo:

```
@UploadSizeLimit(sizeLimit=40 * 1024 * 1024, fileSizeLimit=10 * 1024 * 1024)
```